# How do I add an array to Parameter in swagger yii2?

Tags: yii2, swagger

How to add descriptions of such parameters to body in a request in swagger (`yii2`).

Composer require

> "yii2mod/yii2-swagger": "*"

I try to write a method in api using swagger

That's what he return:

```
{
"parent_id":"",
"name":"testCategory3",
"position":"0",
"status":"1",
"publish-status":"1",
"charsName":["1","2","3"]
}
```

My description:

```
   /**
     * @SWG\Put(path="/api/createCategory",
     *     tags={"Category"},
     *     summary="Create Category",
     *     @SWG\Parameter(
     *         name="Authorization",
     *         in="header",
     *         description=" ID",
     *         required=true,
     *         type="string"
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Parameter(
     *         name="body",
     *         in="body",
     *         required=true,
     *         @SWG\Schema(
     *             type="object",
     *             @SWG\Property(property="parent_id", type="integer" ),
     *             @SWG\Property(property="status", type="integer" ),
     *             @SWG\Property(property="publish-status", type="integer" ),
     *             @SWG\Property(property="position", type="integer" ),
     *             @SWG\Property(property="name", type="string" ),
     *         )
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response = 200,
     *         description = "Ok",
     *         @SWG\Schema(ref = "#/")
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response = 400,
     *         description = "Bad Request",
     *         @SWG\Schema(ref = "#/")
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response = 404,
     *         description = "Not Found",
     *         @SWG\Schema(ref = "#/")
     *     ),
     *     @SWG\Response(
     *         response = 500,
     *         description = "Internal Server Error"
     *     )
     * )
     */
```

How to add charsName array?

[In swagger page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSCb4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array property is defined using `type="array"` and `@SWG\Items`:

```php
     *             @SWG\Property(
     *               property="charsName",
     *               type="array",
     *               @SWG\Items(type="string"),
     *               example={"1","2","3"}
     *             )
```

Comment: Many thanks. 
And can you tell me how to wrap this into an array?

Comment: This annotation, when added to your `@SWG\Schema`, corresponds exactly to `"charsName":["1","2","3"]` in your original post.